# insert into select with external key reference

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO trees (preview) 
select galleries.preview 
from galleries,trees 
where trees.id=galleries.idTree;
```

I am trying to move a column from a table to another, I have set an empty column with the same data type as the original.

Where `idTree` is equal to `id` to the destination table (in the source table `idTree` is foreign key reference to `id` on `trees` that is the destination).

The "select" works and give me back the right set of values (at least ordered by id and all) but the `insert into` part, do nothings and the field on trees is still empty. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please run a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` foreach table involved in the question.. And give basic information about the records in the table..  Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  so we know what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT INTO..` will create a new row; but you are looking to update the existing rows in `trees` table which has id. Try with `UPDATE` query instead:

```
UPDATE trees 
JOIN galleries ON galleries.idTree = trees.id
SET trees.preview = galleries.preview
```

Comment: like a blind...thanks for pointing me in the right direction.